# vscode always ask for permission to save

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Ubuntu and here is my issue:
VSCode is always asking for permission to save any edit on any file.

I just want to edit and save without having to enter my password every time so is this possible on Ubuntu?
I tried to add a new user, but I see also the same problem.
I tried to run VSCode as root, but it said it's dangerous to run it as root.

How can I avoid this permission step when saving a file with VSCode?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Make sure that you (as an Ubuntu user account) are the owner of the folder and files you are editing in VSCode:

```
cd /path/to/my/files
chown -R $USER:$USER .
```

Note: If you are not the user, you might have to precede that with `sudo`:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .
```

(Note: full stop makes you the owner of the files in the parent directory)

Answer (score 36):

`sudo chmod -R 777 filename` works for the file's parent folder.

Comment: This is a good solution, but if you do that, you may change the permission for all the files in a project and you're going to commit all the files again. It may cause some trouble for other contributors in the project

Answer (score 25):

This is a common problem. You don't want to change the owner:group of your files and you don't want to run VSCode as root for security reasons. Here's my solution, with a little background info.
On a typical web server, the web files will be owner:group www-data:www-data (for example) - only the owner (www-data)has write permission.
VSCode runs under the $USER account, not www-data, so it has no write permission.
You can't change VSCode to run as www-data (not easily) so the alternative is to add $USER to the www-data group, and give the folders write permission for the group. This is only a little less secure than the group having only read permissions - acceptable in my view on a development machine.
Add yourself to the www-data group:

```
sudo usermod -aG www-data $USER
```

This won't take effect immediately, you need to su to yourself then logout and back in

```
su $USER
```

Check that you're in the www-data group

```
id
```

Logout and in again. Next, change the permissions on /var/www/html (or wherever you're trying to write to):

```
sudo chmod -R ug+rw /var/www/html
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

Re-start VSCode and your user should now have write permissions for the folder.
If for any reason you accidentally change directory permissions, you can restore them with:

```
sudo find /var/www/html -type d -execdir chmod 750 {} +
```

Comment: If you still have permissions problems and are using a web server this worked for me:
After adding yourself to the group change the files owenrship to $USER:www-data
and set files permissions to 755

`sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www/html/
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/`

Answer (score 15):

There are basically three types of solutions as far I know

1. Running VS Code with the `root` privileges ( **not recommended** )

   `sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"`

If you run this command from the terminal, VS Code will start with the root privileges, but running a user-level application, with root privileges is potentially dangerous because if some vulnerability found in VS Code, that might affect your system. VS Code also warns you about this.

[image: img_warning]

2. Using `chmod -R 777` command ( **It depends** )

`sudo chmod -R 777  your_project_directory_location`

Example

```
 sudo chmod -R 777 /var/opt
```

If you use this command, not only you, other users on the machine also able to see, modify your project. Because `chmod 777` gives full control over the file to everyone. So, only use this command if you want to share your project with others.

3. Using `chown` command ( **Recommended**)

`cd location`

`sudo chown your_username your_project_directory`

Example

let's say I have a directory called `project1` in my `/var/opt` location and my user name is `mir`

```
cd /var/opt


sudo chown mir project1
```

However, if you already created some file before applying `chown`, don't forget to change their permission also

`sudo chown your_username your_project_directory/your_file_name`

Use the -R flag to recursively change the ownership of the contents of that directory.

Example

```
sudo chown mir project1/file1.txt
```

It's recommended because it neither creates any security issue nor giving unnecessary access of your projects to the others. Its solve your problem by keeping your's project up to you

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when you have your file (which you're trying to save using vscode) is in such a location on your pc which requires super user permissions to perform changes. To run vscode as root we can run it like this using terminal:

```
sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root
```

But it is not recommended to run vscode as root, as sudo permissions are only required for administrative purposes. The better option would be to move your project to a location where sudo permissions are not required (like Desktop etc.).

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

use visual code as a super user using below command

> sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root

Thanks,
Shani

Answer (score 1):

to work with xampp do:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

and then you can just save like a human beiing with `ctrl+s` and no "retry as sudo"

How can you let the website refresh automatically when saving php files in htdocs?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below cmd which will open VS Code in admin mode.

### sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"

Comment: That is not recommended. The correct is to give files the read/write permission for non sudo users. VSCode as admin does not runs well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation. I installed it via Ubuntu store. However it seems the lastest version is using snap, even within the store. I did not have snap installed probably. I uninstalled via ubuntu store and then installed it via terminal.

```
sudo snap install --classic vscode
```

It removed some errors, however i still had the saving problem. But atleast now the folders existed it tried to write to.
But after checking files, i was not owner on some of them, so you need to make sure you are the owner and the problems should be gone, Look at the accepted answer for make ownership of your files.

Now the error is misleading within vscode due to asking for permission for `/snap/vscode/{version}` folder, but if your files you wanna save has owner permssioner as your user, the problem disappears.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo chown -R nameofuser:groupofuser *
```

nameofuser and groupofuser can be found by `ls -al` command
you must be in the parent folder :) hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 and because this was the first time I had to install it in place of my host machine, I messed up and forgot to create partitions. Now I am doing all my work on the same partition in which the Linux kernel is present, so VS Code always asks for "sudo" permission to save.

This worked for me:

If your code which you want to edit in VS code is present in `MyApplication/` folder, run this in your terminal

```
sudo chmod -R 777 MyApplication/
```

This will do the trick.